# save output in csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
def execute():
    d = read_input_file_mock()
    lst = []

    for in in d:
        if in.get("Message"):
            message = in.get("Message")
            message = json.loads(message)
            in_string = message.get("in")
            lst.append(in_string)
    data = json.dumps(list(set(lst)))
    return data
```

**output**

["5700302618082", "4063617555079", "4048803188064", "4017182874431", "4006175499096", "0098132561704", "5700302496406", "4056867023092"]

want to save this result in csv file as a integer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`csvwriter.writerows`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) to write each element of your list in one separate line:

```
import csv

with open("path_to_the_outputfile.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows([[row] for row in data])
```

##### # Output (.csv)

```
5700302618082
4063617555079
4048803188064
4017182874431
4006175499096
...
```

If you need to add a header (e.g `List_of_Numbers`), use [**`csvwriter.writerow`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) :

```
with open("path_to_the_outputfile.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['List_of_Numbers'])
    writer.writerows([[row] for row in data])
```

Comment: i'm getting output like this :   """"
4
0
6
6
3
5
9
7
6
1
7
9
1
""""
","
 
""""
3
6
1
4
2
7
3
8
8
2
4
7
7
""""

Comment: What's the type of `data` ? Can you `print(type(data))` ? `json.dumps` normally returns a string. If so, you need to convert it to a list with `json.loads(data)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.DataFrame(np.array(your_data,dtype="int64")).to_csv('your_path.csv')
```